# Will player style magic resistance help a pet resist conflict?

Tags: nethack

I equipped a Djinni with a spare GrayDSM and an amulet of reflection, so I'm sure she's good to go. But I'm nearing the point of fighting Rodney for his book, and after that,...  Lotsa monsters. She's pretty high levelled (L14), but I'm not clear on how the formula using MR, ML, etc. is affected by conflict or if player MR helps at all (the wiki doesn't specify in any of the relevant articles). It would be nice to use conflict provided she doesn't turn on me.  Does the GDSM help?

Answer (score 1):

[Magic Resistance](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Magic_resistance) does a great job of stopping beams, polymorphs, and death magic, but is not known to be effective against mind altering enchantments.  What it covers is enumerated in the link above.

Magic Cancelation is effective against the magical side effects of physical blows.  So no help here.

All in all, Conflict is incompatible with pets.